# Can't print from POS using IOTBox

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm running an Odoo v15 CE instance and using the POS module. I'm trying to print the orders to the kitchen and for that reason, I did set up an IOTBox that is connected to the printer.

I have added the IP address of the IOTBox under the POS settings and also added a new "Printer" in the POS settings and set its proxy IP to the IP of the IOTBox.

When I try printing I get an error that says "Unknown Error". There are no errors in the Odoo instance logs or the IOTBox logs. I have also noticed that the Odoo instance is not even trying to connect to the IOTBox as the firewall hasn't captured any packets going out of the instance destined to the IOTBox.

I don't have the IoT Module installed as I'm using Odoo CE. I understand that if I'm just using a printer I can put the IP address of the IOTBox directly and don't need that module. Is that correct?

IOTBox: Version 21.10

Thanks,
Marcos.